# unable to prove the property that uniform metric is actually a metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Definition of uniform Topology: Let $\Gamma$ be a non empty set and let $\bar{d}$ be the standard bounded metric on $\mathbb{R}$ . Define a metric $\bar{\mathbb{\rho}}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{\Gamma}$ by  $\bar{\mathbb{\rho}}(x,y)$= {lub${\bar{d}(x_{\alpha} ,y_{\alpha})}: \alpha \in \Gamma$}.Then $ \bar{\mathbb{\rho}}$ is a metric called uniform metric and topology induced by $\bar{\mathbb{\rho}}$ is called uniform topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\Gamma}$.

> I am unable to prove triangle inequality for $\bar{\rho}$,

I have proved it till here:$\frac{ d(x_{\alpha} , y_{\alpha})} { 1+ d(x_{\alpha}, y_{\alpha})} \leq \frac{ d(x_{\alpha} , z_{\alpha})} { 1+ d(x_{\alpha}, y_{\alpha})} +  \frac{ d(z_{\alpha} , y_{\alpha})} { 1+ d(x_{\alpha}, y_{\alpha})}$.

Can you please help me in completing the proof of triangle inequality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s easiest to do by contradiction.

Suppose that $\bar\rho(x,y)>\bar\rho(x,z)+\bar\rho(z,y)$; then by the definition of least upper bound there is an $\alpha\in\Gamma$ such that

$$\bar d(x_\alpha,y_\alpha)>\bar\rho(x,z)+\bar\rho(z,y)\,.$$

But $\bar\rho(x,z)\ge\bar d(x_\alpha,z_\alpha)$, and $\bar\rho(z,y)\ge\bar d(z_\alpha,y_\alpha)$, so

$$\bar d(x_\alpha,y_\alpha)>\bar d(x_\alpha,z_\alpha)+\bar d(z_\alpha,y_\alpha)\,,$$

contradicting the fact that $\bar d$ is a metric on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I think $\bar\rho(x,z)\ge\bar d(x_\alpha,z_\alpha)$ and $\bar\rho(z ,y)\ge\bar d(z_\alpha,y_\alpha) $( 5 th line of your answer) is not true, In fact the converse holds

Comment: @Tim: It’s correct as written: $\bar\rho(x,z)$ is an **upper bound** for the numbers $\bar d(x_\alpha,z_\alpha)$, so it is by definition at least as big as all of them.